# "SELECT... WHERE column > ?1" - what is that?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring, fast-learned it for a few days and need to fix an old service in my workplace.

I've got a JPA repository, and some of the methods with `@Query` contains this weird  `> ?1` inside of them.

It looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface LeadsRepository extends JpaRepository<LeadEntity, Long> 
{

    @Query(value = "select /*long query*/ where p.acceptedAt > ?1 and 
          p.acceptedAt < ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Stream<LeadEntity> findPendingPackages(date begin, date end);
}
```

What does it mean? also how can it be that it selects both >1 and <2 ? it should select nothing then...

P.S - I 'm also a SQL newbie so go easy on me :)

Comment: If I had to guess, `?1` would refer to the first parameter of your method, `begin`, and `?2` would refer to the second parameter, `end`.

Comment: @JacobG. WELL! that sounds super logical, taking into account that It does have to query only packages in a certain time window... thank you :)

Comment: @Gibor See the documentation [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) for more info.  Specifically, section 5.1.

Comment: @Jordan You have the start of a good answer there, if you just include some details from the link. Hint, hint. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "select /*long query*/ where p.acceptedAt > ?1 and 
          p.acceptedAt < ?2", nativeQuery = true)
Stream<LeadEntity> findPendingPackages(date begin, date end);
```

this mean that the `?1` refer to the first param of method => `date begin`

and `?2` referrs to the seconde param `date end` etc ...

So `findPendingPackages` should return all package that their `acceptedAt` date is between `date begin` and `date end`

so you can pass SQl parameters by using the `?` , and you have to respect the number and the order of those in your method

see [here in doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for further info

Also you can use  **Named Parameters** like `:paramname` to prevent ordering error or number if you have a lot of param to send , by example  your query would be

```
@Query(value = "select /*long query*/ where p.acceptedAt > :begin and 
          p.acceptedAt < :end", nativeQuery = true)
Stream<LeadEntity> findPendingPackages(@Param("begin") date begin,@Param("end") date end);
```

Comment: perfect! thanks for the detailed explanation and extra info :)